# Converting c# methods to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, automapper, dto

How can I convert these two `ConvertDtoListToAddresses` and `ConvertDtoListToDocuments` C# methods to a `generic`?  I've tried passing in two generic type variables, but when I get down to 'Add' in the loop I get stuck on various errors.  Converting from a DTO to its respective DBO is done in the constructor of the DBO, which I think is part of the problem.

```
private void ConvertDtoToPerson(PersonDTO dto)
{
    Id = dto.Id;
    Fname = dto.FirstName;
    Mname = dto.MiddleName;
    Lname = dto.LastName;
    Suffix = dto.Suffix;
    Maiden = dto.MaidenName;
    Addresses = ConvertDtoListToAddresses(dto.AddressesDto); // want to convert to generic
    Documents = ConvertDtoListToDocuments(dto.DocumentsDto); // want to convert to generic
}

private static ICollection<Address>? ConvertDtoListToAddresses(ICollection<AddressDTO>? addressesDto)
{
    if (addressesDto is not null && addressesDto.Any())
    {
        ICollection<Address> addys = new List<Address>();

        foreach (AddressDTO dto in addressesDto)
        {
            // Converts from dto in constructor
            addys.Add(new Address(dto));
        }

        return addys;
    }

    return null;
}

private static ICollection<Document>? ConvertDtoListToDocuments(ICollection<DocumentDTO>? documentsDto)
{
    if (documentsDto is not null && documentsDto.Any())
    {
        ICollection<Document> docs = new List<Document>();

        foreach (DocumentDTO dto in documentsDto)
        {
            // Converts from dto in constructor
            docs.Add(new Document(dto));
        }

        return docs;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
Addresses = ConvertDtoListToType<Address, AddressDTO>(dto.AddressesDto);
```

```
private static ICollection<T>? ConvertDtoListToType<T, D>(ICollection<D>? dtoCollection)
{
    if (dtoCollection is not null && dtoCollection.Any())
    {
        ICollection<T> tList = new List<T>();

        foreach (D dto in dtoCollection)
        {
            tList.Add(new T(dto));  // <-- This is where I'm having trouble
        }

        return tList;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried AutoMapper

Comment: It looks like 90% of your boilerplate would be eliminated by LINQ `.Select`.

Comment: `dtoCollection?.Select(x => new Document(x)).ToList()`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Zee Yes, I'm familiar with AM and have used it in the past, but am trying to get away from it.

Comment: @NickBailey It can, I used the suggestion from Enigmativity below, thanks!

Comment: @AmanB It was related to not being able to new up a T that the where constraint issue Phillip Ngan mentioned wasn't able to solve.  Not an issue now tho as this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of a `Func<D, T> factory` parameter would sort this out.

```
private static ICollection<T>? ConvertDtoListToType<T, D>(ICollection<D>? dtoCollection, Func<D, T> factory)
{
    if (dtoCollection is not null && dtoCollection.Any())
    {
        ICollection<T> tList = new List<T>();
        foreach (D dto in dtoCollection)
        {
            tList.Add(factory(dto));
        }
        return tList;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do keep in mind that that is **almost** the semantic equivalent of this:

```
private static ICollection<T>? ConvertDtoListToType<T, D>(ICollection<D>? dtoCollection, Func<D, T> factory)
    => dtoCollection?.Select(d => factory(d))?.ToList();
```

I'd question the idea that an empty `dtoCollection` should return a `null` final collection anyway. This is probably a better implementation.

So, having said that, your original method offers very little functionality benefit. It's code for code's sake. A simple `Select`/`ToList` pair keeps your code simple.

In any case, you can provide a static method off of `Address` and `Document` to provide the `Func<D, T>` that you need.

```
public class Address
{
    AddressDTO dto;

    public static Address CreateFromDto(AddressDTO dto)
        => new Address(dto);

    public Address(AddressDTO dto)
    {
        this.dto = dto;
    }
}
```

Now, calling it is like this:

```
var addresses = ConvertDtoListToType(addressDtos, Address.CreateFromDto);
```

Or:

```
var addresses = addressDtos?.Select(Address.CreateFromDto)?.ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Ended out forgoing all that extra code and just using the Select with CreateFromDto combination.  Works perfectly and so much cleaner.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to be able to provide a constraint on the Type `T` to say that it has a constructor that takes a parameter of type `D`. Something like this:

```
private static ICollection<T>? ConvertDtoListToType<T, D>(
  ICollection<D>? dtoCollection) where T : new(D) 
{}
```

But this does not exist in C#. The workaround is to provide a factory method to create your type `T` given a type `D`. i.e. Something like:

```
private static ICollection<T>? ConvertDtoListToType<T, D>(
  ICollection<D>? dtoCollection, Func<D, T> factory)
{
    // Use factory(dto), instead of new T(dto)
}
```

But as @Zee says, you should have a look at Automapper, which can convert between types of collections.

Comment: Helpful, thanks!  I ended out using the solution Enigmativity suggested.